# Disabling button issue based on checkbox multi-selection ?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have to disable delete button for particular status dynamically and i am doing that successfully for some extent but its failing when i am doing multi selection .

```
$(".checkboxes").click(function () {
        var currentstatus;
        var blnEnableBtn = false;
        $('input:checked').each(function (index, element) {
            currentstatus = $.trim($(element).closest('td').siblings()[2].innerText);
            if (currentstatus == "hit" || currentstatus == "average")
                blnEnableBtn = true;
            else
                blnEnableBtn = false;
        });

        if (blnEnableBtn)
            $("#btnDeleteRow").removeAttr('disabled');
        else
            $("#btnDeleteRow").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    });
```

As metioned in my code i am enabling delete button for `hit` and `average` statuses and for remaining all i am disabling it .

**Scenario 1 (single select) :** works fine when u select single checkbox everytime .

**Scenario 2  (multi select):** select check box with status 'Dead' and then select checkbox with  'hit' status you can observe 'Delete' button will be `enabled` which should not happen in my case as in a multi selection and there is a status of 'Dead' type which should make button disabled on overall which is not happening .

Any workaround is appreciated

Comment: So you want to disable button if at least one status is "hit" or "average"? Then just add `if (blnEnabledBtn === true) return;` as a first line in your `each` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, you should rewrite your `each` function as follows:

```
$('input:checked').each(function (index, element) {
    currentstatus = $.trim($(element).closest('td').siblings()[2].innerText);
    if (currentstatus == "hit" || currentstatus == "average")
        blnEnableBtn = true;
});
```

So now, you set `blnEnabledBtn` to true only for desired statuses (else statement is not needed), and if those statuses were not met, it stays false.

**Edit:**

The first solution enables the button, but apparently that is not what should happen. Ok, let's reverse the logic:

```
var blnEnableBtn = true;
$('input:checked').each(function (index, element) {
    currentstatus = $.trim($(element).closest('td').siblings()[2].innerText);
    if (currentstatus != "hit" && currentstatus != "average")
        blnEnableBtn = false;
});
```

Now, in case there is at least one checkbox with not desired status, the button is disabled.

**Edit 2:**

After some clarifications, I've finally understood the issue. It can be solved by adding extra flag, like this:

```
var blnEnableBtn = false;
var skipTheRest = false;
$('input:checked').each(function (index, element) {
    if (skipTheRest === true)
        return;
    currentstatus = $.trim($(element).closest('td').siblings()[2].innerText);
    if (currentstatus == "hit" || currentstatus == "average")
        blnEnableBtn = true;
    else {
        skipTheRest = true;
        blnEnableBtn = false;
    }
});
```

See working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fcmx6sq0/2/).

Comment: @supercool What is your final goal on multiselect? To disable button or to enable? What conditions should be met?

Comment: disable @llya if i select multiple checkboxes out of then if anyone is `not` of status of `hit` and `average` i should disable button .

Comment: ty for your efforts but still it wont work . say if i select a check box of other status and uncheck it then the button getting enabled which should not happen . now single select is misfiring

Comment: I lost it. Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fcmx6sq0/) for your code, what's wrong with it?

Comment: i am shocked its everything fine with fiddle but nothing right in vs2012 . i can only explain my issue in words . see `case 1` : if i select checkbox with status 'hit' the button enables [foreach runs one time] . `case 2`: if again i check some other status now the issue is `foreach` runs 2 times and on first run button will be disabled going into if condition and on second run the button will enabled going into else condition WHICH is clearly not incase of fiddle . i can debug in vs . wierd . OVER-riding is happening

Comment: any way i can jump from if condition and foreach if i get  `blnEnableBtn = false;` . this will help me i guess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60219/discussion-between-ilya-luzyanin-and-super-cool).

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is when you click one checkbox, you initiate it to all at once. That is why it works, if its just one checkbox.
You want to give each checkbox its own listener that keeps its actions within the same checkbox.

```
$(".checkboxes").each(function() {
  $(this).click(function(){
      //Do something awesome
  })
});
```

This should be a good start : )